# Watch app custom menu image not showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I am just creating watch app and adding custom menu image but it's not showing.

Got this guideline - [Menu Image Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/MenuImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014992-CH18-SW1)

And created the icon 80x80 in png format.

Naming it comment.png.

What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Edit 1- Added images in WatchAppImages.xcassets and now its looking like - 
[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work

Comment: try now, its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling  `setContextMenuOptions` in your WKInterfaceController?

```
- (void) setContextMenuOptions
{
     [self addMenuItemWithImageNamed:imageName title:title action:action];
}
```

And, where is the image added? should be in WatchAppImages.xcassets  not in WatchExtensionImages.assets.

Also, your png should be name for retina display: iconImage@2x.png added in your assets in the blue square of the next image(in 2x, not for 1x or 3x):

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am adding from storyboard, let me try this.

Comment: Ok, basically is what I did on my app and works fine. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: I added image in question,Please check it, now its looking like attached image.

Comment: is your custom image? How looks your expected menu?

Comment: Expected menu have Red colour canvas with white icons.

Comment: As far as I know (probably Im wrong) we can't change the background color of the context menu, its always black. Maybe because a black background blends seamlessly with the device bezel and maintains the illusion of there being no screen edges.

Comment: can you please send me one sample icon which you are using - arun.sharma@moxilogy.com ?

Comment: I've just sent you. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Worked, Thanks. It was image issue.

Comment: Hi, @JavierFloresFont can you please send me a sample icon too. I am facing similar issue. I have tried everything given in the apple guideline, but it somehow doesn't seem to work. My email - zeeshan.ahmed@teks.co.in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @San007 if you have the sample can you send me. My email - zeeshan.ahmed@teks.co.in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its working now. I was adding the image in the wrong location. I was adding it in the WatchKit Extension image asset instead of WatchKit App image asset